# On row clicking, pass record id to linkbutton inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

**Scenario**

I have a gridview. On clicking a row a modal window is shown.

Inside the modal window, there are a few link-buttons.

**Problem**

I need to pass the ID of the record clicked to the PostbackURL attribute of the link buttons inside the modal, so that the user is able to click the link and view record details.

**Example**

1. User clicks on a recordID=30;
2. Modal window is shown with links to record detail pages;
3. Links urls contain the correct recordID (30);
4. User clicks on link and details page is displayed.

**What I've tried**

(I've used Jquery)

```
row.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e) { $(this).find('#editPosition').attr('href') = ~/People/Details.aspx?PersonID=" + key + ";})$('#myModal').modal('show')";
```

where 'Key' is the recordID.

I thought this would do it, but I'm obviously missing something.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Can we see the context of your code? That one line doesn't really help us grasp the problem, I feel like if you are using an event handler for the click, you can easily pass the id

Comment: I tried to use the editPosition_Click event handler. The problem with that was that the url contained the ID of the last record bound in the grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this.

The issue was caused by:

1. not using properly the attr() method and
2. not calling properly the 'show' event for the modal.

In order to work the original snippet should have been like this:

```
row.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {$(this).find('.modal-body #editPosition').attr('href', '~/People/Details.aspx?PersonID=" + key + "')}).modal('show');";
```

Comment: I have now moved the Jquery fucntion in the markup page. I call the function from code behind by passing in the key argument.